# Template event selector 'not' isn't working

Tags: javascript, meteor

In this Meteor template code, when the `canvas` is clicked, it prints out the `canvas` element to the console but it is expected not to fire the event.

How can it be made so that it fires if the element which is clicked is not a `canvas`?

```
Template.myTemp.events({
  'click *:not(canvas)': function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an interesting problem as the `:not` selector is supported by Blaze, and works properly with other HTML elements. You might want to open an issue about this in the [Blaze repo](https://github.com/meteor/blaze).

The above being said, there are a few different ways you can work around this. You could add a check in your event handler to make sure you don't do anything with `canvas` related events:

```
Template.myTemp.events({
  'click *'(event, instance) {
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'canvas') {
      // Handle non-canvas events ...
    }
  },
});
```

Another option involves chaining your event handlers, if you want to be able to filter out `canvas` events specifically. For example:

```
Template.myTemp.events({
  'click canvas'(event, instance) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // Handle canvas click events only ...
  },
  'click *'(event, instance) {
    // Handle all click events except canvas click events, since they're 
    // captured and handled above ...
  },
});
```